# IOS GLKit : Rendering loop stopped

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiscrollview, glkit

Odd issue, I made this prototype project which was a GLKit render with a UIScrollview over the top to move the rendered object.  Had to use CADisplayLink etc to make it work well as scrolling would stop the rendering.  ALL was fine!

I have then copied the classes in to another project and fired it up, again everything appeared to work fine except that its not firing the rendering loop every x times a second.  Just once (until the scrollview calls it).

What could stop the method below from being automatically called?

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, weirdly the controller was paused.  I am not sure how and why but

self.paused = NO; (GLKViewController) fixed it